# Fargate service discovery for eureka clients

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, aws-fargate, service-discovery

We are planning to host our eureka discovery server in the same vpn as our fargate services. What configuration we have to provide in our client container configuration to enable them to seamlessly connect with our discovery server. The discovery server is not hosted on fargate , it is on separate EC2 machine.

Comment: How have the microservices been developed? Are they Spring Boot apps?

Comment: yes using eureka server and eureka client in spring boot

Answer (score 0):

You need to point the clients to the Eureka server including the following configuration on the client's `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: <client-name>
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

The EUREKA_URI environment variable need to be set on containers with the Eureka address. The additional localhost URL allows apps run without containers on dev workstations along with a local copy of Eureka (just another boot app).

Comment: Need some clarification. What will be the EUREKA_URI in case of production if it is in the same vpc . Can we access it without load balancer.

Comment: You will need a load balancer when running multiple Eureka servers for HA. Otherwise, it can point directly to the Eureka Server address. Don't forget to add the port number and the `/eureka` path.